# How to get value from $http function in angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, json

I've create a function in angular. And it is working fine and can get correct result but my problem is i want particular node from result. i have worked with JSON and Jquery, but i am new in angular.

This is my code.

```
$scope.booking= function(docid,addid){
    //console.log(addid);
    var a =  $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "http://localhost:81/DoctorStayServiceAngular/model/getDoctorBookingDetail.php",
        params:{"doctorid":docid,"addressid":addid,"day":weekday[d.getDay()]}
        //params:{"doctorid":docid}
    }).then(function mySucces(response) {
        //$scope.count= response.data;
        /*$scope.appo=[];

        $scope.appo= i;
        i++;*/
        //      
        //console.clear();
        return response.data;
    });
    console.log(a);
    return a;
};
```

http://localhost:81/DoctorStayServiceAngular/model/getDoctorBookingDetail.php

return following json.

```
{
    "status":"success",
    "message":"",
    "booking":{
        "booking_detail":[{
            "session":null,
            "slot":null,
            "day":"Friday"
        }]
    }
}
```

This how i can see in firebug
[image: This is what i can see in firebug]

Expanded view
[image: Expanded view]

so i want to get value(which I've highlighted in image) from response(which is under $$state), what should i do?

in short how can i get bottom result?

```
{
    "status":"success",
    "message":"",
    "booking":{
        "booking_detail": [{
            "session":null,
            "slot":null,
            "day":"Friday"
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: `{"status":"success","message":"","booking":{"booking_detail":[{"session":null,"slot":null,"day":"Friday"
}]}}` there is no `value` in this result. If it's typo then `response.value` is your answer.

Comment: yes there in no value in result but as in when i print console log there is value node under $$state, as you can see in image.

Comment: `$scope.result = response;` or `response.data` console response once, result must be  
`{"status":"success","message":"","booking":{"booking_detail":[{"session":null,"‌​slot":null,"day":"Friday" }]}}`

Comment: `a` is the `$http` promise. You need to use `then()` on return of function as shown. SHow where you use this function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$http service returns a promise(this is printed in your console logs), which will be resolved after that http call is complete.

Please go through this $q documentation on how deferred data works.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

This should work,

```
$scope.booking= function(docid,addid){
        $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: "http://localhost:81/DoctorStayServiceAngular/model/getDoctorBookingDetail.php",
                params:{"doctorid":docid,"addressid":addid,"day":weekday[d.getDay()]}
                //params:{"doctorid":docid}
            }).then(function mySucces(response) {
                $scope.responseData = response.data;
            });
        };
```

After this you can bind the data in responseData to your view.